# Shopify JSONP issue in ajaxAPI

Tags: ajax, jsonp, shopify, defects

I'm getting some odd response back from shopify ajaxapi for jsonp.

If you cURL a Shopify ajax api location

```
http://storename.domain.com/cart.json?callback=handler
```

you will get a jsonp response. But something is breaking the same request in browsers.

It appears to be related to compression? Here are some responses from each browser when attempting to call the jsonp as documented.

- Firefox: The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
- Internet Explorer: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
- Chrome/Safari/Webkit: Cannot decode raw data, or failed (chrome)

Attempted use via jquery:

```
$.getJSON('http://storename.domain.com/cart.json?callback=?', function(data) { ... });
// Results in a failed request, viewable network request panels of dev tools
```

Here is some output from cURL including response headers:

```
$ curl -i http://storename.domain.com/cart.json?callback=CALLBACK_FUNC

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 18 Dec 2012 13:48:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
ETag: cachable:864076445587123764313132415008994143575
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Alternate-Cache-Key: cachable:11795444887523410552615529412743919200
X-Cache: hit, server
X-Request-Id: a0c33a55230fe42bce79b462f6fe450d
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Set-Cookie: _session_id=b6ace1d7b0dbedd37f7787d10e173131; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Runtime: 0.033811
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"

CALLBACK_FUNC({"token":null,"note":null,"attributes":{},"total_price":0,...})
```

Also related unanswered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750841/shopify-ajax-api-jsonp-supported

Thanks

Comment: If you want to send a message directly to Shopify support, you should send it directly to Shopify support. I don't understand what part of your question is supposed to be answered by the SO community.

Comment: @Blazemonger, Shopify support directed me here and asked me to submit a shopify tagged question

Comment: This is being fixed. Watch @shopifyapi on Twitter and I can send out a notice when it's done.